# document.onmousemove / onmmouseup prevent selecting text in IE input or textarea

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, select, text, onmousemove

whenever i alter the onmousemove or onmouseup attributes of the document, for example:

> document.onmousemove = myOnMouseMove;
>
> document.onmouseup = myOnMouseUp;

It prevents me from selecting text in any **input type='text'** or **textarea** elements in internet explorer (have tried in ie7 and ie8, fine in firefox). If I remove *either* of these it allows me to select text again, but i really need both to make my home made drag and drop functionality work elsewhere on the page.

Is there some way i can retain the default functionality of the onmouseXXX functions and attach my function onto the end? Or is there a better way to be doing this?

I also have the same problem using the onkeyup attribute of a textarea forcing the flashing text cursor to the end of the text.

Thanks

Comment: These are properties, not attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine so long as you don't return `false` from your event handler functions or mess with the user selection. Alternatively, you could check the event's target in the event handler to filter out `<input>`s and `<textarea>`s:

```
document.onmousedown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var tagName = target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (tagName == "input" || tagName == "textarea") {
        // Do nothing
    } else {
        // Do your stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, i managed to fix it by toggling the onmousemove "property" to null when it wasnt dragging, but this code could definately be usefull somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

If you need drag-and-drop, which seems to be the reason to want this in the first place, I can warmly recommend *not* trying to code that yourself. Instead, use a popular framework like YUI, or jQuery. They are reasonably lightweight and offer reasonable cross-browser compatibility. Really, it's no fun reinventing this wheel.

Comment: thanks for the advice, if i had to do it again i would probably go down that path, but for now its all coded and working the way i want it to apart from this one last bug..
Cheers